# Android: Размещение изображения размером более 4096x4096

Tags: android, android-imageview

Мое приложение генерирует изображения размером более 4096x4096, как объект Bitmap. И я хотел бы разместить это изображение в imageView в полном разрешении. До этого сжимал наибольшую сторону до 4000 пикселей, а вторую пропорционально до первой и получал на выходе изображения к примеру 50x4000, когда в оригинале было 250х20000. Можно ли как-то решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Неясно в чем, собственно, проблема. Было 250х20000, сократили большую сторону до 4000, получили 50х4000. Что не так?

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий то что на выходе получается очень узкое изображение, а иногда генерируется изображение размером около 250х40000, тогда на выходе получаю 25х4000. Очень смазанное и ничего не видно

Comment: А чего иного вы ожидаете от ужатия картинки в десять раз? Если ужимать узкую картинку, то она так и останется узкой.

Comment: @Эникейщик верно, поэтому я хочу разместить картинку без ужимания. ImageView у меня находиться внутри ScrollView и я могу по горизонтали его листать

Comment: Ну так размещайте. Проблема-то в чем?

Comment: @Эникейщик в том, что в imageView стандартно нельзя загружать изображения с разрешением более 4096х4096. Сейчас изучаю библиотеку Picasso, но я не уверен, что это то, что мне нужно

Comment: Сделай row, положи в scrollview и загрузки там 10 картинок без ужимок.

Comment: Что в Вашей задаче не так. Не правильно грузить настолько большие изображения - половина старых девайсов будут крэшиться с сообщением о нехватке памяти.